# Unable to access localhost through mobile

Tags: android, localhost

I have read many answers in forum, but i am not able to connect to server of my pc.Here is what i have tried:-
1)making wifi hotspot through connectify.
2)using connectify's pc ip as a url to connect to the localhost.
But no success.
can anyone suggest me what i am missing.

Comment: what's your connection protocol??

Comment: Still there is no problem with code,first i have to connect my phone to server, which is the real problem.

Comment: did u add internet and wifi state permission on your manifest

Comment: @arun i just want my phone browser to connect to localhost

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device/15864222#15864222

Comment: @arun some improvement,first the error was Connection_failed, now it is Proxy_connection_failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the http,https sharing via wifi network.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, You should turn off your firewall in your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Just Turn Off the firewall  **(Private Network)**.
[[image]]